# iOS 7 uinavigationcontroller how to detect swipe?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

In the new iOS 7 `UINavigationController`, there is a swipe gesture to switch between views.
Is there a way to detect or intercept the gesture?

Comment: `I won't disable it`. You make it sound like you're being "naughty"

Comment: It's just because I read a similar topics about "how to disable swipe gesture in uinavigationcontroller". So I wanted to be clear ^^

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The interactive pop gesture recognizer is exposed through `UINavigationController`'s `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property. You can add your own controller as a target of the gesture recognizer and respond appropriately:

```
@implementation MyViewController

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(handlePopGesture:)];
}


- (void)handlePopGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // respond to beginning of pop gesture
    }
    // handle other gesture states, if desired
}

...

@end
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644597/1677912), in Swift. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift) to construct the selector, I found the following to work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.handlePopGesture))
}

func handlePopGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        // respond to beginning of pop gesture
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not responding for me... i just wanted to print "hello" on gesture recognize

Comment: I had to add `@objc` in front of `func handlePopGesture` to make it valid code.