# @selector() in Swift?

Tags: swift, selector, nstimer

I'm trying to create an `NSTimer` in `Swift` but I'm having some trouble.

```
NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: test(), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

*`test()` is a function in the same class.*

---

I get an error in the editor:

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

When I change `selector: test()` to `selector: nil` the error disappears.

I've tried:

- `selector: test()`
- `selector: test`
- `selector: Selector(test())`

But nothing works and I can't find a solution in the references.

Comment: `selector: test()` would call `test` and pass it's return value to the `selector` argument.

Answer (score 963, accepted):

Swift *itself* doesn't use selectors — several design patterns that in Objective-C make use of selectors work differently in Swift. (For example, use optional chaining on protocol types or `is`/`as` tests instead of `respondsToSelector:`, and use closures wherever you can instead of `performSelector:` for better type/memory safety.)

But there are still a number of important ObjC-based APIs that use selectors, including timers and the target/action pattern. Swift provides the `Selector` type for working with these. (Swift automatically uses this in place of ObjC's `SEL` type.)

#### In Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3) and later (including Swift 3 / Xcode 8 and Swift 4 / Xcode 9):

You can construct a `Selector` from a Swift function type using the `#selector` expression.

```
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: object,
                  selector: #selector(MyClass.test),
                  userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
button.addTarget(object, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonTapped),
                 for: .touchUpInside)
view.perform(#selector(UIView.insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)),
             with: button, with: otherButton)
```

The great thing about this approach? A function reference is checked by the Swift compiler, so you can use the `#selector` expression only with class/method pairs that actually exist and are eligible for use as selectors (see "Selector availability" below). You're also free to make your function reference only as specific as you need, as per [the Swift 2.2+ rules for function-type naming](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID400).

(This is actually an improvement over ObjC's `@selector()` directive, because the compiler's `-Wundeclared-selector` check verifies only that the named selector exists. The Swift function reference you pass to `#selector` checks existence, membership in a class, and type signature.)

There are a couple of extra caveats for the function references you pass to the `#selector` expression:

- Multiple functions with the same base name can be differentiated by their parameter labels using the aforementioned [syntax for function references](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID400) (e.g. `insertSubview(_:at:)` vs `insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)`). But if a function has no parameters, the only way to disambiguate it is to use an `as` cast with the function's type signature (e.g. `foo as () -> ()` vs `foo(_:)`).
- There's a special syntax for property getter/setter pairs in Swift 3.0+. For example, given a `var foo: Int`, you can use `#selector(getter: MyClass.foo)` or `#selector(setter: MyClass.foo)`.

#### General notes:

**Cases where `#selector` doesn't work, and naming:** Sometimes you don't have a function reference to make a selector with (for example, with methods dynamically registered in the ObjC runtime). In that case, you can construct a `Selector` from a string: e.g. `Selector("dynamicMethod:")` — though you lose the compiler's validity checking. When you do that, you need to follow ObjC naming rules, including colons (`:`) for each parameter.

**Selector availability:** The method referenced by the selector must be exposed to the ObjC runtime. In Swift 4, every method exposed to ObjC must have its declaration prefaced with the `@objc` attribute. (In previous versions you got that attribute for free in some cases, but now you have to explicitly declare it.)

Remember that `private` symbols aren't exposed to the runtime, too — your method needs to have at least `internal` visibility.

**Key paths:** These are related to but not quite the same as selectors. There's a special syntax for these in Swift 3, too: e.g. `chris.valueForKeyPath(#keyPath(Person.friends.firstName))`. See [SE-0062](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0062-objc-keypaths.md) for details. And even more [`KeyPath` stuff in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md), so make sure you're using the right KeyPath-based API instead of selectors if appropriate.

You can read more about selectors under [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*.

<sup>**Note:** Before Swift 2.2, `Selector` conformed to `StringLiteralConvertible`, so you might find old code where bare strings are passed to APIs that take selectors. You'll want to run "Convert to Current Swift Syntax" in Xcode to get those using `#selector`.</sup>

Comment: Putting a string with the function name worked, NSSelectorFromString() works also.

Comment: I'd like to mention that while "Interacting with Objective-C APIs" is on the website, it is NOT in 'The Swift Programming Language' book.

Comment: This should probably mention that the selector needs a ":" at the end if it takes an argument. (E.g. test() -> "test" & test(this:String) -> "test:")

Comment: Heads up: the third argument in the "addTarget" statement (forControlEvents) needs a period ( . ) in front of TouchUpInside.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the Cocoa frameworks expect an Objective-C style method name. If your method takes an argument you will need a ':' if it takes 2 arguments,  `size:andShape:`, if the first argument is named you may need a `With`, i.e. `initWithData:` for `func init(Data data: NSData)`

Comment: I would use the "@objc func" answer below personally.

Comment: Is there anyway to add validation around passing the "selector" as a string? IE compiler warn us when we misspell, etc.

Comment: Is it true way to use String as selector in Swift while in ObjC runtime it is decleared as _typedef struct objc_selector *SEL_ ?

Comment: Also note that the selected method cannot be private, otherwise it will not be able to find the method.

Comment: @rickster is there a way that the selector in Swift can checked at compile time?

Comment: I must add that selector function should be declared without **private** modifier.

Comment: @confile: belated follow up: No, but that's little different from ObjC... The warning you get from passing garbage to `@selector()` only checks whether that selector is known to your project, not whether it's valid to call on a specific target.

Comment: If I attempt to use just "selectorNameHere" swift now throws an error for me, using Selector("selectorNameHere") works. This works:             item.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: menuIcon, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("showSideMenu"))

Comment: @rickster For Swift 2.2, they might like a link to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994

Comment: In Swift 2.2, it looks like the method may be private, but if it is then it needs to have the `@objc` attribute, even if it subclasses `NSObject`.

Comment: How can I use selector inside a struct. It gives me error that "@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes"

Comment: 素晴らしい答えです！ （少し古くなっている場合。)

Answer (score 96):

Here's a quick example on how to use the `Selector` class on Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("method"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}

func method() {
    // Something cool here   
}
```

Note that if the method passed as a string doesn't work, it will fail at runtime, not compile time, and crash your app. Be careful

Comment: which is horrible... is there a "NSStringFromSelector" type of thing ?

Comment: can't believe they designed for unchecked selectors since objc had this

Comment: @malcomhall: `@selector` is handy, but it's not enforced as formally as you might think. "Undeclared selector" is merely a warning from the compiler, because new selectors can always be introduced at run time. Verifiable/refactorable selector references in Swift would be [a good feature request to make](http://bugreport.apple.com), though.

Comment: This answer is helpful but the answer below with @objc is more appropriate.

Comment: When you are passing the selector string in as a variable or parameter, you'll need to let the compiler know its a selector using the Selector() function.  thanks

Comment: Since `Selector` conforms to `StringLiteralConvertible`, you can just use a plain string instead of the `Selector(…)` construct.

Answer (score 48):

Also, if your (Swift) class does not descend from an Objective-C class, then you must have a colon at the end of the target method name string and you must use the @objc property with your target method e.g.

```
var rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("method"))

@objc func method() {
    // Something cool here   
}
```

otherwise you will get a "Unrecognised Selector" error at runtime.

Comment: 1. selectors w/ a colon must take an argument 2. according to Apple docs timer's actions should take NSTimer argument 3. `Selector` keyword is not mandatory. So in this case signature must be `@objc func method(timer: NSTimer) {/*code*/}`

Comment: `@objc` worked for me. I didn't need to include `timer: NSTimer` in my method signature for it to be called.

Answer (score 37):

**Swift 2.2+ and Swift 3 Update**

Use the new `#selector` expression, which eliminates the need to use string literals making usage less error-prone. For reference:

```
Selector("keyboardDidHide:")
```

becomes

```
#selector(keyboardDidHide(_:))
```

See also: [Swift Evolution Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md)

**Note (Swift 4.0):**

If using `#selector`you would need to mark the function as `@objc`

Example:

`@objc func something(_ sender: UIButton)`

Answer (score 29):

**Swift 4.0**

you create the Selector like below.

1.add the event to a button like:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickedButton(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

and the function will be like below:

```
@objc func clickedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Comment: You forgot to put `@objc` before `func` which is required in Swift 4.

Answer (score 26):

For future readers, I found that I experienced a problem and was getting an ***`unrecognised selector sent to instance`*** error that was caused by marking the target `func` as private.

The `func` **MUST** be publicly visible to be called by an object with a reference to a selector.

Comment: it doesn't **have** to be public you can still keep the method private but add `objc` before it's declaration. Ex: `@objc private func foo() { ...` then you can use `"foo"` as a selector as much you like

Comment: It can also be `internal`, thus not specifying any access modifier. I often use this pattern: `//MARK: - Selector Methods\n extension MyController {\n func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {`

Answer (score 21):

Just in case somebody else have the same problem I had with NSTimer where none of the other answers fixed the issue, is really important to mention that, if you are using a class that do not inherits from NSObject either directly or deep in the hierarchy(e.g. manually created swift files), none of the other answers will work even when is specified as follows:

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "test", 
                    userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
func test () {}
```

Without changing anything else other than just making the class inherit from NSObject I stopped getting the "Unrecognized selector" Error and got my logic working as expected.

Comment: The issue with this alternative is that you can´t change a class (let´s say ViewController) to inherit from NSObject, given that you need the ViewController class implemented stuff (e.g. viewDidLoad()). Any idea how to call a Swift function within a ViewController using NSTimer?... e

Comment: UIViewController already inherits from NSObject, most classes exposed by the SDK do, this example is for your own created classes that require NSTimer functionality...

Answer (score 15):

If you want to pass a parameter to the function from the NSTimer then here is your solution:

```
var somethingToPass = "It worked"

let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "tester:", userInfo: somethingToPass, repeats: false)

func tester(timer: NSTimer)
{
    let theStringToPrint = timer.userInfo as String
    println(theStringToPrint)
}
```

Include the colon in the selector text (tester:), and your parameter(s) go in userInfo.

Your function should take NSTimer as a parameter.  Then just extract userInfo to get the parameter that passed.

Comment: I was using NSTimer(0.01, target: self, ...) which did NOT work, whereas using NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, ..) DID work!? Strange but thanks @Scooter for you answer!

Comment: @iOS-Coder just creating a timer with the initialiser does not add it to a runloop, whereas `scheduledTimerWith...` automatically adds it to the current runloop - so there is no strange behaviour here at all ;)

Comment: @David thanks for your suggestion. I guess my misunderstanding should belong in either STFW or RTFA (Read The F...ing API) category?

Comment: Don't worry about it, no one can be expected to read the documentation about every single method in every API ;)

Answer (score 12):

Selectors are an internal representation of a method name in Objective-C. In Objective-C "@selector(methodName)" would convert a source-code method into a data type of SEL. Since you can't use the @selector syntax in Swift (rickster is on point there), you have to manually specify the method name as a String object directly, or by passing a String object to the Selector type. Here is an example:

```
var rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Logout", 
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
    target: self, 
    action:"logout"
)
```

or

```
var rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Logout", 
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
    target: self, 
    action:Selector("logout")
)
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.1**

 With sample of tap gesture

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dismiss(completion:)))

// Use destination 'Class Name' directly, if you selector (function) is not in same class.
//gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DestinationClass.dismiss(completion:)))


@objc func dismiss(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
}
```

See Apple's document for more details about: [Selector Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/selector-expression)

Comment: Please stop doing this. It helps no one. How is this any different from Swift 3.1? And why did you think it necessary to add another answer to this when it already has about 20 answers?

Comment: calling selector is different in swift 4. Try these answers in swift 4 and see. None these will work without editing. Please do not mark any statement as spam without ensuring its impotance

Comment: So is there any reason you couldn't edit the existing, accepted answer? It would make it actually useful rather than adding on the end of a long list of answers. The "Edit" button is there for a reason.

Comment: Also, which part of this is different from Swift 3?

Comment: You have to add the objc tag to any selectors for Swift 4. This is the correct answer. And your not supposed to edit other people's answers to change their meaning. @Krunal is totally right.

Comment: I have a question about this answer. I understand the need for the @objc in the declaration. My question is about the use of `self.dismiss(completion:))) rather than a class type identifier i.e. MyCustomUIView.dismiss(completion:))). All the docs I can find in swift-evolution appear to follow the type-id format suggested in [swift-evolution/.../proposals/0022-objc-selectors](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/d3b4fed228c3f39e236059ad47750c6abdcc9753/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md). Is using the iVar 'self' now required or that that a convenience you've adopted?

Answer (score 7):

```
// for swift 2.2
// version 1
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tappedButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.tappedButton2(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

// version 2
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedButton2(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

// version 3
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
buttton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton2(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func tappedButton() {
  print("tapped")
}

func tappedButton2(sender: UIButton) {
  print("tapped 2")
}

// swift 3.x
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  // tapped
}

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton(_:_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton, _ event: UIEvent) {
  // tapped
}
```

Comment: it would have been nicer and more educative if u had an example taking two or three arguments for Swift3 or Swift4  too. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Objective-C Selector**

Selector identifies a method.

```
//Compile time
SEL selector = @selector(foo);

//Runtime
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"foo");
```

For example

```
[object sayHello:@"Hello World"];
//sayHello: is a selector
```

`selector` is a word from `Objective-C` world and you are able to use it from `Swift` to have a possibility to call `Objective-C` from `Swift`  It allows you to execute some code at runtime

Before `Swift 2.2` the syntax is:

```
Selector("foo:")
```

Since a function name is passed into `Selector` as a **`String`** parameter("foo") it is not possible to **check** a name in **compile time**. As a result you **can** get a runtime error:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

After `Swift 2.2+` the syntax is:

```
#selector(foo(_:))
```

Xcode's autocomplete help you to call a right method

Answer (score 5):

```
Create Refresh control using Selector method.   
    var refreshCntrl : UIRefreshControl!
    refreshCntrl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshCntrl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshCntrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Please Wait...")
    refreshCntrl.addTarget(self, action:"refreshControlValueChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    atableView.addSubview(refreshCntrl)
```

//Refresh Control Method

```
func refreshControlValueChanged(){
    atableView.reloadData()
    refreshCntrl.endRefreshing()

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Swift 3.0 is published, it is even a little bit more subtle to declare a targetAction appropriate

```
class MyCustomView : UIView {

    func addTapGestureRecognizer() {

        // the "_" is important
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyCustomView.handleTapGesture(_:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    // since Swift 3.0 this "_" in the method implementation is very important to 
    // let the selector understand the targetAction
    func handleTapGesture(_ tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if tapGesture.state == .ended {
            print("TapGesture detected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be useful to note where you setup the control that triggers the action matters.

For example, I have found that when setting up a UIBarButtonItem, I had to create the button within viewDidLoad or else I would get an unrecognized selector exception.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    // add button
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "746-plus-circle.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("addAction:"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
}

func addAction(send: AnyObject?) {     
    NSLog("addAction")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `performSelector()`

`/addtarget()/NStimer.scheduledTimerWithInterval()` methods your method (matching the selector) should be marked as

```
@objc
For Swift 2.0:
    {  
        //...
        self.performSelector(“performMethod”, withObject: nil , afterDelay: 0.5)
        //...


    //...
    btnHome.addTarget(self, action: “buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    //...

    //...
     NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector : “timerMethod”, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    //...

}

@objc private func performMethod() {
…
}
@objc private func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton){
….
}
@objc private func timerMethod () {
….
}
```

For Swift 2.2,
you need to write '#selector()' instead of string and selector name so the possibilities of spelling error and crash due to that will not be there anymore. Below is example

```
self.performSelector(#selector(MyClass.performMethod), withObject: nil , afterDelay: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

you create the Selector like below.
1.

```
UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Some Title",
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done,
    target: self,
    action: "flatButtonPressed"
)
```

2.

```
flatButton.addTarget(self, action: "flatButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Take note that the @selector syntax is gone and replaced with a simple String naming the method to call. There’s one area where we can all agree the verbosity got in the way. Of course, if we declared that there is a target method called flatButtonPressed: we better write one:

```
func flatButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  NSLog("flatButtonPressed")
}
```

set the timer:

```
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, 
                    target: self, 
                    selector: Selector("flatButtonPressed"), 
                    userInfo: userInfo, 
                    repeats: true)
    let mainLoop = NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop()  //1
    mainLoop.addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode) //2 this two line is optinal
```

In order to be complete, here’s the flatButtonPressed

```
func flatButtonPressed(timer: NSTimer) {
}
```

Comment: Do you have any source for "_Take note that the @selector syntax is gone_"?

Answer (score 3):

I found many of these answers to be helpful but it wasn't clear how to do this with something that wasn't a button. I was adding a gesture recognizer to a UILabel in swift and struggled so here's what I found worked for me after reading everything above:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: "labelTapped:")
```

Where the "Selector" was declared as:

```
func labelTapped(sender: UILabel) { }
```

Note that it is public and that I am not using the Selector() syntax but it is possible to do this as well.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: Selector("labelTapped:"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **#selector** will check your code at compile time to make sure the method you want to call actually exists. Even better, if the method doesn’t exist, you’ll get a compile error: Xcode will refuse to build your app, thus banishing to oblivion another possible source of bugs.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self,
                            action: #selector(addNewFireflyRefernce))
    }

    func addNewFireflyReference() {
        gratuitousReferences.append("Curse your sudden but inevitable betrayal!")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As many have stated selectors are an objective c way of dynamically calling methods that has been carried over to Swift, it some case we are still stuck with it, like UIKit, probable because they where working on SwiftUI to replace it but some api have more swift like version like Swift Timer, for example you can use

```
class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, 
                                            repeats: Bool, 
                                              block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer
```

Instead, you can then call it like

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, 
                              repeats: true ) {
    ... your test code here
}
```

or

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, 
                              repeats: true,
                              block: test)
```

where the method test takes a Timer argument, or if you want test to take an named argument

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, 
                              repeats: true,
                              block: test(timer:))
```

you should also be using `Timer` not `NSTimer` as `NSTimer` is the old objective-c name

Answer (score 1):

Change as a simple string naming in the method calling for **selector syntax**

```
var timer1 : NSTimer? = nil
timer1= NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("test"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

After that, type func test().

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

//Sample code to create timer

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

WHERE
timeInterval:- Interval in which timer should fire like 1s, 10s, 100s etc. [Its value is in secs]
target:- function which pointed to class. So here I am pointing to current class.
selector:- function that will execute when timer fires.

func updateTimer(){
    //Implemetation 
} 

repeats:- true/false specifies that timer should call again n again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Selector in Swift 4:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score -2):

**For swift 3**

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Function declaration In same class:

```
@objc func test()
{
    // my function
}
```

Comment: If target is self, then there is not need to have `self` in selector.

This should be enough:
```let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)```