# Is there a typesafe way to use selectors in Swift?

Tags: selector, swift, type-safety

For the most part, Swift is a huge improvement over Objective-C in terms of type safety. One glaring exception is selectors. In Objective-C, using the expression `@selector(notARealSelector:)` will give a compiler warning. The Swift equivalent, `Selector("notARealSelector:")` will always compile but will fail at runtime.

Is there a typesafe way to use selectors in Swift, so I can work with Objective-C APIs that require them?

I have a lot of `NSNotification` observers in my app and would like to have some kind of compile-time checking that I'm not making typos in my selectors.

**Edit**: The specific use case is `NSNotificationCenter.addObserver`.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're using the `@selector()` block currently? Do the objects you're calling those methods on expose (either through protocol conformance or subclassing) the methods at any time? You can use `myDelegate?.scrollViewDidScroll?(...)`, but this requires the delegate at least conform to the protocol so the compiler has a chance at determining if it's even possible for that method to be there.

Comment: Like I said in the question, `NSNotificationCenter.addObserver`

Comment: Another common use of @selector is the target/action used by `UIControl` and subclasses. e.g. `button.addTarget(self, action: "doTap", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)` - frustrating that the swift compiler cannot warn of mistakes due to typos or method names changing.

Comment: not a specific answer to your question about general type-safety with swift selectors, but if you want to maintain type safety in this specific case, there is a version of this notification call that takes a block instead of a selector: `public func addObserverForName(name: String?, object obj: AnyObject?, queue: NSOperationQueue?, usingBlock block: (NSNotification) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol`. see https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-implement-an-nsnotification-observer-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typesafe selectors were just released in Xcode 7.3 beta 4:

```
let sel = #selector(insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)) // sel has type
```

`Selector` is now a first class citizen and comes with some nice Swift compiler warnings. If needed you can still pass in a string:

```
let sel = Selector("propertyName")
```

See a much more complete answer here: [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Xcode Release Notes: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3_beta_4/Xcode_7.3_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: @Bill See also my discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35658335/341994 This explains thoroughly the new `#selector` syntax. It only took them, what, two years since you (rightly) asked your question to come up with this... :) In my opinion this hole in the type-safety has been, all this time, a massive contradiction of all that Swift is supposed to stand for. Now the hole has been filled.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Swift notion of *optionals* as:

```
if let result = object.notARealSelector?(/* args */) {
   // Use Result
}
```

where the *?* used following `notARealSelector` with return `false` to `if` when there is no such method defined on the type of `object`.

There is a caveat for [*optional protocol requirements*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_365):

> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol is marked
>        with the @objc attribute. Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, 
>        you need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to specify 
>        optional requirements.

But since your are asking about optional methods in the first place, you must be talking about this in the Objective-C context.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, I'm trying to pass selectors to `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: Also, treating a function as an optional works only for optional protocol methods — you can't do `object.notARealSelector` unless `object` is a variable/constant of protocol type and said protocol is an `@obcj` protocol that declares `notARealSelector` as an `@optional` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection to get the names of an object's properties as strings, as summed up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24124749/957768), but that won't make the connection between an identifier and its string name the way `@selector` does in ObjC. Some creative use of reflection might work around that problem, but you might also do well to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).