# Replacing literal string in action:

Tags: ios, swift

There is a way to replace plain text in `action:` in swift?

For example `UIBarButton` code:

```
var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "H", style: .Plain, target: self.someTarget(), action:"someStringAction:")
```

The one way to do it i think is <s>`NSStringFromSelector(Selector(someStringAction()))`</s>, but the problem with that is my target is not `self`.

I can create a method in target class to call above method and return `String` but I'm not sure this is correct way to do it.

Whole point of question is: **How to avoid using literal strings when you call a methods?**

Comment: Have no idea on what you are trying to do. Can you clarify it?

Comment: I don't want to use string to method call. Typo can build without warning. I want to have error on buildtime when method is not there.

Comment: When you are using the selector, it is by design that no compile time error. Selector is very dynamic, which is dispatched in runtime.

Comment: if you've done @selector(something:) in objective-c you'll get an error. I'm looking for sth similar to this but in swift. And if swift does not even has selectors (there are strings afaik) I have no idea where to look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122703/is-there-a-typesafe-way-to-use-selectors-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Either completely replace the `UIBarButtonItem` with a new selector string or change the tag on the `UIBarButtonItem`.  The tag would represent a certain action to take when the selector is called.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by completly replace with new selector string.