# Function is not being called using UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swift

Exactly what the title implies. How do the gesture recognizers work, specifically UIGestureRecognizer. Here is a small snippet of my code

`var keyboardDismiser: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gestureRecognizer:")
        keyboardDismiser.direction = .Right | .Left
        noteView.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismiser)`

and

```
    func gestureRecognizer(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
    println("swipe")
    self.view.endEditing()
}
```

My goal is to dismiss the keyboard when switching from view to view in a UIScrollView with 3 pages. What am I doing wrong? There isn't much documentation on this in Swift.

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: The code is not working, the keyboard doesn't dismiss and there is no console output that says "swipe"

Answer (score 2):

First you setting the recognizer on the note view. It will only be active on the note view.

In addition, you are not setting `direction` correctly. You are setting then changing the it's value. To set it to both right and left, you use the `|` operator. Also `direction` knows it a `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection` so you don't need specify that.

```
var keyboardDismiser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gestureRecognizer:")
keyboardDismiser.direction = .Right | .Left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismiser)
```

Finally, I would use `endEditing()` instead of `resignFirstResponder()`.

```
func gestureRecognizer(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
    println("swipe")
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code is still not working. It seems like the function is not being called.

Comment: @elito25 update the question: in what method do you have `keyboardDismiser`?

Comment: The keyboardDismiser is in the ViewController method under viewDidLoad while the gestureRecognizer function is within ViewController but not under ViewDidLoad

Comment: @elito25 sorry, I don't know if I can be of much more help. You will need to attach a debugger and look at the view hierarchy, see if there is something which interferes with the gesture.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I am looking up the combination of UIScrollView and UIGestureRecognizers and it seems like they don't play well together.

Comment: I am looking at it using a debugger to find the hierarchy, and it isn't even showing up.There is no Gesture recognizer in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that selectors in Swift do not need the `:` at the end; they're just a string with the name of the function: `gestureRecognizer`. So this is what you should have:

```
var keyboardDismiser = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "gestureRecognizer")
```

Relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift).