# Trouble with NSTimer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I tried this but nothing happened. Is there something wrong with the selector?

```
    func timer() {
       var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector:Selector("function"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func function() {
       println("it worked")
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I called on the timer function.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift. The selector thing is not really a thing in Swift.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're just creating the timer, but not adding it to the run loop. You'll either need to use the equivalent `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method or schedule it on the run loop with `addTimer:forMode:`.

Comment: It tried using the first option you stated and it didn't fire either.

Comment: @user: Is this in an environment where a run loop is running?

Comment: How do I tell if a run loop is running?

Comment: @user3746375: If it's a normal AppKit or UIKit app with a functioning interface that doesn't have any alerts or menus open, it probably has a running run loop. If that isn't the case and you don't know if you have one, you probably don't.

Comment: To add a timer to a run loop: Swift 3: `RunLoop.current.add(myTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code for your `NSTimer`:

**Swift 2**

```
func timer() {
   var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
func timerFunc() {
   println("it worked")
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func timer() {
    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
@objc func timerFunc() {
    print("it worked")
}
```

You have to use the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` class method to run your timer.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you create the Selector like below.

```
let @Selector : Selector = "timerFireMethod:"
```

and then create the timer

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, 
                target: self, 
                selector: @Selector,
                userInfo: userInfo, 
                repeats: true)
```