# NSTimer isn't updating a label

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nstimer

So I'm trying to make a function refresh every 1 second so it updates a label, unfortunately it's not trigger for some reason. Code below with comments.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tt_CountDown: UILabel!


    var tt_currentDate = NSDate()
    var tt_objCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.timeClassManagement()

       //The timer I'm using to call the function to repeat
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timeClassManagement"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func timeClassManagement(){
        //the function that holds the code for the label below
        tt_CountDown.text = "\(String(tt_hour)):\(String(tt_minute)):\(String(tt_second))"

    }



}
```

Comment: The timer isn't actually suppose to stop. It's a clock for the most part. How would I go about proving tt_CountDown is not nil? New to Swift... Thank you for your response!

Comment: If it is not supposed to stop then you are going to run into memory problems if this view is ever reloaded (You will have two timers, then three, then four, etc)

Comment: However, where do you actually update tt_hour tt_minute, etc?

Comment: At the current moment I'm just concerned with getting the label to update, but I'll certainly take that into account when I get to it.

Edit: tt_hour and tt_minute are defined in the timeClassManagement

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No issues in console @rdelmar

Comment: Have you tried putting a log into the timeClassManagement method to confirm whether it's called or not?

Comment: @matt, he would get an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error if the outlet were nil.

Comment: @rdelmar Hey, since the code changes the label wouldn't that be a sign that the function has been called?

Comment: Did you say it changed the label? I thought the problem was that it wasn't changing the label.

Comment: @rdelmar Ah sorry, the problem is NSTimer isn't updating the label, it's suppose to be counting up from the current time of the day. The label changes and shows the current time, but NSTimer is suppose to be updating it every second to show that its counting up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63531/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user3708761).

Comment: So the chat with @rdelmar didn't happen, still stuck on this.

Comment: I'm back in the chat room, of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with he timer failing to call its action method; that is working fine. The problem is in the code you used to update the label (from our chat).

```
func timeClassManagement(){ 
var tt_objDateFormat = tt_objCalendar.components( .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: tt_currentDate) 

var tt_hour = tt_objDateFormat.hour 
var tt_minute = tt_objDateFormat.minute 
var tt_second = tt_objDateFormat.second 

tt_CountDown.text = "\(String(tt_hour)):\(String(tt_minute)):\(String(tt_second))" 

}
```

The date you're using, tt_currentDate, is the same every time the method is called. You need to pass in the current date so it will change.

```
var tt_objDateFormat = tt_objCalendar.components( .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate:NSDate.date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a string of the function name to the `NSTimer` init.  Selectors are an ObjC construct, and methods that accept selectors can be given strings in Swift.

First `timer` should be a property.  It'll be gone by the time `viewDidLoad` ends.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timeClassManagement", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

More detail is offered in this answer to a similar question: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/3879

Comment: I've already done this, running your version hasn't helped either unfortunately...

Comment: Just to be sure, you've connected the `UILabel` to the outlet in Interface Builder, yes?

Comment: I have

@IBOutlet var tt_CountDown: UILabel!

Just beneath the class for ViewController

Comment: I don't mean the code, I mean Interface Builder.  Your storyboard, is the `tt_CountDown` connected the label in the storyboard/xib?

Comment: tt_CountDown is connected to the main storyboard.