# Programatically instantiating UIBarButtonItem throws missing argument exception

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

I am trying to do something very simple in Swift - instantiate a UIBarButtonItem:

```
let btnImg = UIImage(named: "imgName")
let btn = UIBarButtonItem(image: btnImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: doSomthing)
```

This code results in a build failure:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'landcapeImagePhone' in call
```

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:landscapeImagePhone:style:target:action:), both functions are available:

**initWithImage:style:target:action:**

```
init(image image: UIImage?,
    style style: UIBarButtonItemStyle,
    target target: AnyObject?,
    action action: Selector)
```

**initWithImage:landscapeImagePhone:style:target:action:**

```
init(image image: UIImage?,
    landscapeImagePhone landscapeImagePhone: UIImage?,
    style style: UIBarButtonItemStyle,
    target target: AnyObject?,
    action action: Selector)
```

If I implement the second init though, I get the following error:

```
Extra argument 'landscapeImagePhone' in call
```

Does anyone know a way in which I can achieve what I am trying to achieve? Is this a bug in Swift / Xcode? I'm running Xcode 6.1.1.

I have done a clean (Cmd + SHIFT + K) and a build folder clean (Cmd + alt + SHIFT + K).

Comment: how is `doSomthing` declared?

Comment: func doSomething() { ... }

Comment: Then use `let btn = UIBarButtonItem(image: btnImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doSomthing")` notice the String at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `doSomthing` is a function without parameters, the correct way to instantiate the `UIBarButtonItem` should be:

```
   let btn = UIBarButtonItem(image: btnImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doSomthing")
```

Check this post for info about `Selectors` in swift :
[@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)