# 4 Questions about Selectors in Swift

Tags: swift

Sorry for these questions

I have 4 questions about Selector in swift.

**FIRST Question**

I am wondering what is the proper way to use selector in swift

```
closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: self, action: Selector("closeBarButtonItemClicked:"));
```

VS

```
closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: self, action: "closeBarButtonItemClicked:");
```

Should we use Selector("methodName:") or "methodName:" right away?

Both way works but which one is the correct way?

**SECOND Question**

How do we call a function with a parameter in Swift? Let's say I want to call a function like this

```
func methodName(parameterOne : String, parameterTwo: String)
```

**THIRD Question**

How do we call a type method using Selector in swift? is it even possible at all?

```
class SomeClass {
class func someTypeMethod() {
// type method implementation goes here
  }
}
```

**FOURTH Question**

What is the purpose of that colon behind the function name in Selector?

Comment: As to your last question, there is no colon after the function name.  The colon is *a part of* the function name.  The function named `xyz:` is an entirely different function from the one named `xyz`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift this post has a detailed explanation on selectors

Comment: Don't beg for rep or upvotes. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @EricD Please help me remove the rest of the ones I did. Didn't know it is not allowed.

Comment: Don't worry, I've reverted these edits. Just avoid doing this sort of thing in the future. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Question 1:
I don't think there is really a correct way. I personally prefer the second way, but both work so I don't think it really matters.

Question 2:
I just reread you question. I think you mean how to call that in a selector. The selector for that I believe would be `"methodName:parameterTwo:"` but I am not positive, as the selector with two parameters probably should have an external parameter name to place in the selector where parameterTwo is in my answer.

Old question 2 answer (prior to edit):
You would call that function as `methodName(variable1, parameterTwo: variable2).` If you wanted to make them say the parameter name in the call you could make the header `methodName(calledVarName parameterOne: String, calledVarName2 parameterTwo: String)`. This would be called as `methodName(calledVarName: variable1, calledVarName2: variable2)`. You could also define the header as `methodName(#parameterOne: String, #parameterTwo: String)`. This would be called as `methodName(parameterOne: variable1, parameterTwo: variable2)`. Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Question 3:
I can't say for sure, but I dont think there is a way to make a selector for this. If there is I assume it would be "someTypeMethod"

Old question 3 answer (prior to edit): 
You can call this method by `SomeClass.someTypeMethod()`.

Question 4: 
The colon signifies that the function header has a parameter. So `"function1:"` corresponds to `func function1(someParameterName: AnyObjectHere)` while `"function1"` corresponds to `func function1()`.

Comment: Very nicely answered!

Answer (score 17):

@ad121's answer is great—just want to add a little context to #1:

The `Selector` type has been extended in Swift to be `StringLiteralConvertible`. Any time a `Selector` instance is expected, you can give a string literal instead and a `Selector` instance will be created for you. This means you can also create a `Selector` instance from a string literal manually:

```
let mySelector: Selector = "methodName:withParameter:"
```

Note that this *doesn't* mean a `String` can be used interchangeably with a `Selector`—this only works with string literals. The following will fail:

```
let methodName = "methodName:withParameter:"
let mySelector: Selector = methodName
// error: 'String' is not convertible to 'Selector'
```

In *that* case you'd need to actually call the `Selector` constructor yourself:

```
let methodName = "methodName:withParameter:"
let mySelector = Selector(methodName)
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering your 3rd question: You can totally do this. Just set the target parameter to the type itself.

Say you have a class defined:

```
class SomeType {
    class func someMethod() {}
    func someMethod() {}
}
```

Now taking your example, this will call the instance method:

```
let something = SomeType()
let closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: something, action: "someMethod")
```

Change the target and the call will get forwarded to the type:

```
let closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: SomeType.self, action: "someMethod")
```