# Swift dynamic selector call (the old performSelector:)

Tags: swift, selector

I'm porting my project in Obj-C to Swift and I'm stuck in this method where I have:

```
textView: NSTextView, doCommandBySelector commandSelector: Selector) -> BOOL
```

in my objc code I had before

```
[textView performSelector:commandSelector withObject:nil];
```

but in Swift I have no idea about the solution, how to actually write the line of code.

Anyone have the solution for this?

I'm going crazy truly for the last week, even after reading tons of documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Swift views selectors as inherently unsafe, and as far as I know does not support the old "performSelector".  There is a Selector type in Swift, but it's uses are somewhat limited.  Look around stack overflow, and you'll see some discussion on the use of timers as a work around.

Comment: See [@selector() in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: I already looked around stack overflow for a solution but I truly do not understand how to write that line of code in Swift. Do you know how maybe?

Comment: I tried timers too, it works but when I hit the delete key to correct/delete, it goes against the 'complete:' method.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Objective-C you have to use method `-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]` for this so in Swift try somethings like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    .sendAction(commandSelector, to: textView, from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

More info on [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998951).

Answer (score 0):

Future readers might like to know that `performSelector` and other members of the same family are available as of Swift 2.