# i have error in func createDetailView() this function

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

i have error in func createDetailView() this function

[image]

func handleProductGesture(recognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {

```
    if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left == recognizer.direction)
    {
     self.rightScrollBtnPressed(nil)
    }
    if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right == recognizer.direction)
    {
      self.leftScrollBtnPressed(nil)
    }


}
```

func createDetailView()
    {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(320*(pageImages.count)), scrollView.frame.height)
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.bounces = false

```
    let rightSwipe = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(handleProductGesture()))
    rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    rightSwipe.delegate = self

    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    let leftSwipe = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(handleProductGesture()))
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    leftSwipe.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

     next = indexNumber-1
    self.rightScrollBtnPressed(nil)

}
```

Comment: What error? Which line?

Comment: Error:- Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Comment: Line :- let rightSwipe = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(handleProductGesture()))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your selector passing code. You need to specify the method names as string there, in your code you are trying to invoke it.

Change those to:

```
let rightSwipe = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleProductGesture:"))

let leftSwipe  = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleProductGesture:"))
```