# Method handler for received Notification crashes the application. :(

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am dealing with the External Accessory Framework and here is my code for registering the notofication..

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().registerForLocalNotifications()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "accessoryDidConnectNotify", name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification, object: nil)
   }
```

And here is my method handling function...

```
func accessoryDidConnectNotify(notification: NSNotification){


        let alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "MFi Accessory Connected", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And my problem is if i dont give any parameters inside the accessoryDidConnectNotify function the application works good proceeding with the alert view when I insert a MFi accessory..

```
(i.e)  func accessoryDidConnectNotify(){   // works fine (with no arguments)
                         }
```

but i need the NSNotification object to be used inside my accessoryDidConnectNotify function to get the name of the accessory
...but if I add the NSNotification object the appliaction crashes on inserting a MFi accessory...

```
(i.e)   func accessoryDidConnectNotify(notification: NSNotification){
}  // crashes app (with arguments)
```

If someone also came across the problem...please do share

Comment: Just change `accessoryDidConnectNotify ` to `accessoryDidConnectNotify:`

Comment: Your function does have one argument, thus the selector name must be `accessoryDidConnectNotify:` as @DharmeshKheni wrote. Here's [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/581190).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method doesn't have any parameter then you can call it this way:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "accessoryDidConnectNotify", name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification, object: nil)
```

by using `"accessoryDidConnectNotify"`.

So that you can use that method like:

```
func accessoryDidConnectNotify(){   // works fine (with no arguments)

     //Your code
}
```

But if your method have parameters then you have to call it this way:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "accessoryDidConnectNotify:", name: EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification, object: nil)
```

By using this `"accessoryDidConnectNotify:"`. here you have to add `:`.

Now you can call your method with parameters this way:

```
func accessoryDidConnectNotify(notification: NSNotification){

    //Your code
}
```