# Mapping an Objective-C selector to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I am using the Google Calendar API for IOS. I've bridged it so that I can use it in swift. Authorisation works great up until the point that the callback is called (i.e I can see in my Google account the authorisation took place).

In [their example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios) they have a selector to handle successful authentication as follows.

```
// Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Google Calendar API
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    //...
}
```

I have translated this selector as follows...

```
func finishedAuthorisation(viewController:GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch?, authResult:GTMOAuth2Authentication?, error:NSError?){
    //...
}
```

... and use it like this ...

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: " ".join(scopes), clientID: kClientID, clientSecret: kClientSecret, keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: "finishedAuthorisation:")
```

... which results in this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation _invocationWithMethodSignature:frame:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read [this nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/581190) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26) - scroll down to Objective-C Selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using this selector `finishedAuthorisation:authResult:error:`

In practice:

**The handling method:**

```
func finishedAuthorisation(viewController:GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch, authResult:GTMOAuth2Authentication, error:NSError?) {
    ...
}
```

**And how I used the selector:**

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope: " ".join(scopes), clientID: kClientID, clientSecret: kClientSecret, keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName, delegate: self, finishedSelector: "finishedAuthorisation:authResult:error:")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your finishedAuthorisation selector takes three arguments. Try putting three colons : "finishedAuthorisation:::"