# UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar for open side menu doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using `UIBarButtonItem` in the navigation bar for open side menu in my project but it does not work.

Here is the code which I implemented:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        self.title=@"Add Money";
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
        //initData
    }
    - (void)setupMenuBarButtonItems {
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self rightMenuBarButtonItem];
        if(self.menuContainerViewController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateClosed &&
           ![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
            // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backBarButtonItem];
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
        }
    }
    - (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
        return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                target:self
                action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
    }
    - (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
            [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a navigation bar in your side menu? If you check self.navigationItem is it not nil?

Comment: Are you sure - (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem is being called? Set a break point inside.

Comment: Yes that method is called.

Comment: - (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}

Comment: But this Method is not call

Comment: - (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}

Comment: Try adding @objc to the declaration of leftSideMenuButtonPressed:.

Comment: In general, there is a wide discussion of relevant problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift