# NSException errror when i call a function with a NSTimer inside

Tags: swift, nstimer

hey i am trying to call a function every 1 second but i keep getting the following error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

this is the code i have and i get the error when i press the button.

```
var startButton : UIButton!
var theTime = 0;
var countDownText = "hello"
var countDownTimer = NSTimer


startButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
startButton.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height/3)
startButton.setTitle("\(countDownText)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
startButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("countDownFunc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(startButton)


func countDownFunc() {

    countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownFunc2:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func countDownFunc2(){
    theTime++
    countDownText = "HELLOOOOOOOOO"

}

print(theTime)
```

i have no clue how to fix this error :(
any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is `countDownFunc()` and `func countDownFunc2()` nested in another method? If yes, put it out. The target/action methods must be located  on the top level of the class.

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the entire function you are currently operating in - I am guessing what @vadian just mentioned is true and I already wrote an answer regarding that. But that can only be verified if you provide a little bit more code context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you defined the method in the wrong scope. You seem to have something like

```
func mySpecialFunc() {
    ...
    startButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("countDownFunc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(startButton)

    func countDownFunc() {
        countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownFunc2:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func countDownFunc2(){
        theTime++
        countDownText = "HELLOOOOOOOOO"
    }

    print(theTime)

}
```

That means that the functions `countDownFunc` and `countDownFunc2` are only defined and available in the scope of `mySpecialFunc`. The object/class you are operating on does not know anything about it and therefore your timer and action selector both fail. What you have to do is move the two methods out of the body of `mySpecialFunc`:

```
func mySpecialFunc() {
    ...
    startButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("countDownFunc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(startButton)

}   

func countDownFunc() {
    countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownFunc2"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func countDownFunc2(){
    theTime++
    countDownText = "HELLOOOOOOOOO"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/5696333).

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "test", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
// cit
```

He didn't use `selector: Selector("method name")`, he use `selector: "method name"`

Comment: That doesn't matter. A `Selector` type can be represented by a literal string, because it conforms to the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol.