# How to use performSelectorInBackground in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, performselector

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc class myClass:NSObject {

        func myFunc(){
            for var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                print(i,[NSThread.currentThread()]);
            }
        }
    }
    var myObj = myClass()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        _ = NSThread.init(target: myObj, selector:Selector(myObj.myFunc()), 

    object: nil)
        }
    }
```

when I run the code above, Xcode has a exception.the information is

> [NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement
>   selector

how to use performSelectorInBackground in swift ??

Comment: `Selector(myObj.myFunc())` will map to a selector corresponding to the return value of `myFunc()`, which is `()`, not to the actual function.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You don't. Use dispatch_async.

Comment: This. The whole `performSelector...` thing is a relic from Objective-C and dynamic dispatch. Moving away from this construct and adopting more modern, agnostic alternatives like GCD ensures better quality Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

A `Selector` is associated with the name of a method represented as a `String`. You're not properly initializing the `Selector`. `Selector` has an initializer that takes a `String`, so you shouldn't be passing it `myObj.myFunc()`. Instead you should be passing it `"myFunc"`.  See this question for more detail:
[@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: change the code to     `_ = NSThread.init(target: myObj, selector:Selector("myFunc"), object: nil)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use perform selector as below:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    _ = NSThread.init(target: myObj, selector:Selector("myFunc"),

        object: nil)
}
```

To perform some task in background you can use dispatcher as an alternative for performSelectorInBackground.

```
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { () -> Void in

        self.myFunc()

    }
```

Comment: **thanks a lot**.I found we can also use **performSelectorInBackground** in function.

Answer (score 0):

Two points need to pay attention：
first, the class which use performSelectorInBackground must inhert NSObject.
second,`performSelectorInBackground(Selector("myFunc"), withObject: nil)` is correct. myFunc is function name.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
performSelector(inBackground: #selector(Selection_Button(url:)), with: finalPath2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the latest syntax for performing a task in the background is:

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
backgroundQueue.async {
    // Do stuff in the background
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Pass to the main queue for UI work etc
    }
}
```

If you're referring to `self` in the background queue you probably want to add `[weak self] in` after the `.async {`.