# What is the concept of selectors in swift?

Tags: swift, selector, nstimer, nsobject

I've seen objects which require the parameter, selector. What is the general concept in understanding a selector?

An example of choosing a selector is the NSTimer where my selector I have chosen is a function that increments the counter.

```
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: ("incrementCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A selector is a concept from Objective-C that represents a message to be sent (i.e. a method to be called) dynamically at run time. When you set up something to be done via a selector, you know which message will be sent, but not necessarily what its parameters are. (And sometimes not even which object it'll be sent to.)

You can consider selectors a relative of closures/blocks, since they let you package up some code to be called later and hand it off to some other function. However, a closure must be specified/resolved at compile time, so it's less dynamic than a selector.

Selectors are great for "loose binding" concepts like control actions. You can use a selector to choose in Interface Builder which method a button should call when clicked, even though your app isn't actually running in IB; or you can say "this button should call `paste:` on whatever text view has keyboard focus", not knowing when you set up the button which view that'll be (because keyboard focus changes all the time).

Selectors in ObjC predate blocks/closures, so historically, selectors were the primary way to tell an API things like "call this method later", which is why you find them throughout Cocoa for patterns like timers, array sorting, and undo even when such patterns might benefit more from the tight binding of closures/blocks.

For more on using selectors in Swift, see [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* and/or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/957768). For more on selectors and Cocoa in general, see [Cocoa Core Competencies: Selector](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH48-SW1).

Answer (score 2):

A `selector` is a custom method which is called in the class specified by `target` when the timer fires. If the method is supposed to take parameters each parameter is represented by a colon.

In Swift the `struct` `Selector` responds to the protocol `StringLiteralConvertible`,
Therefore – since the compiler knows the type in your example – a literal string is implicitly converted to a `Selector` instance and the `Selector` initializer is not needed.

PS: The parentheses around your selector string are not needed either.