# PaintCode animation in Xcode

Tags: xcode, paintcode

I am trying to understand how PaintCode animations can be intergated in Xcode. In my example I have a ball going from right to left.
I want the animation to start as long as the app starts and stop when you stop the stop button.
In the attachments is what i have done so far:

[image: StyleKit]
[image: PCView]

[image: ViewController]

When I run it returns an error:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A few things are wrong here

- First thing that is wrong is that your `drawBall` function is defined with an argument, but you never pass anything to it through the `NSTimer`. You should use the `userInfo` argument of the `NSTimer` initialisation if you want to pass an argument to the timer fire function.
- Second of all, your `NSTimer` is trying to call the selector `"drawBall"`, but your function is defined with an argument. Therefore it should be `"drawBall:"`.
- Third of all, I'm pretty sure the external argument name in your function is interfering with the selector name.

**Try changing it to:**

```
func drawBall(var fraction:CGFloat) {

...

}
```

It's also worth noting that you can define selectors in swift [just by using the string literal syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/2976878) Therefore you could just provide `"drawBall:"` in your `NSTimer`.

**Furthermore, there are a few other things that you'll want to look into...**

- You never pass the `fraction` variable into your `drawRect` method
- You never invoke your `drawRect` method (do this though using `setNeedsDisplay()`)

Comment: try changing the function to `func drawBall(var fraction:CGFloat)`

Comment: Sorry for some reason only the last two lines of your response appeared before. I have provided "drawBall:" in the NSTimer and changed the function to func drawBall(var fraction:CGFloat) . I do not get any crushes now, but as you can guess the ball doesn't move. I am not sure how to use the userInfo argument of the NSTimer initialisation in order to pass an argument, i tried userInfo: ("fraction") but it didnt work..

Comment: no, `userInfo` takes an object, not a primative time like `CGFloat`... what are you using the `fraction` variable for anyway? to me it looks like something that should be an instance variable (up with the `timer` and `counter` variables)

Comment: okay... well you're never passing it into the `UIView`'s `drawRect`.. I think you want to move your animation logic into the `UIView` (including the timer), make the fraction variable an instance variable, and pass the fraction variable into the `drawBall` function (in the StyleKitName2 class)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101315/discussion-between-originaluser2-and-do2).