# Unrecognized selector for instance error Swift

Tags: swift, progress-bar

Im creating a simple typing app with timer. The timer should be in a form of a progress bar that decrements every second.

To implement the progressbar, I intended to set the progress to 0.1 lesser to the current progress every 1 second. But there is an "Unrecognized selector for instance " error when i set the progress. 
Is there any other way to work around.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestView: UIViewController, UITextInputTraits {


    @IBOutlet weak var TestLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TypingField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var time : Float = 0.0
    var timer: NSTimer!
    var test = 0;
    var progress : Float = 1
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var testStringArray = ["abode" , "tutorial" , "completed",
                            "war", "method", "continue",
                            "machine", "texting" , "iterate"]
    var idx = 0;    
    var setProg : Float = 1     

    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {

        let s = TypingField.text!

        if(s.characters.last == " "){
            let word = s.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

            if(!word.isEmpty){
                print(testStringArray[idx])
                if(word == testStringArray[idx]){
                    idx++;
                    TypingField.text = "";
                    TestLabel.text = testStringArray[idx];
                }else{
                    TypingField.text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setProgress() {
        setProg -= 0.1
        progressView.progress = setProg  <-- cannot decrement progress bar

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        TypingField.autocorrectionType = .No
        TypingField.autocapitalizationType = .None 

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:Selector("setProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  

        TestLabel.text = testStringArray[idx];

        TypingField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)                            
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Good chance it is this line causing the problem... `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:Selector("setProgress"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) ` try changing to `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:"setProgress", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: Let me know if that does not work and I'll look more closely

Comment: I second @MikeG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution but still got same error `2016-02-07 19:14:59.474 Typing Test[5611:157671] -[UIView setProgress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe079c591c0
2016-02-07 19:14:59.485 Typing Test[5611:157671] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setProgress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe079c591c0'`

Answer (score 0):

You have coded `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` in a manner like it is done with Objective-C. In Swift it is done differently. Instead of:

```
    selector:Selector("setProgress")
```

just use:

```
    selector:"setProgress"
```

Comment: Hi, I stil got the same error... but when i uncomment `progressView.progress = setProg` the program will just run fine.. maybe setting the progress create the error?

Comment: Have you connected your outlets properly? That is the only other reason I can think for the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance..."

Comment: @MikeG I had checked again,, i think i have.. properly connected it,,

Comment: It sounds like some size-effect is causing that line to fail. Could the progress be going negative? I thought it coped with that though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function declaration for `func setProgress()` to:

```
func setProgress(sender: NSTimer)
```

And change `Selector("setProgress")` to `"setProgress:"`

**EDIT:**

Apparently the method `setProgress` already exists, so you'll need to rename the function, e.g. to `setProgressBar` or something to that effect.

> Method 'setProgress' with Objective-C selector 'setProgress:' conflicts with setter for 'progress' with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: Wouldn't it be `"setProgress"` ? I have only used this syntax -> `"setProgress:"` when dealing with `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: Once you add a sender to (or other parameter) to the function, you need to add the colon at the end of the selector. But apparently `setProgress:` conflicts with another setter, so you should name your function something else. I'm getting: `Method 'setProgress' with Objective-C selector 'setProgress:' conflicts with setter for 'progress' with the same Objective-C selector`

Comment: I still the same error, I added parameter sender. I changed the function name because there's a conflict,, but the error is still there.. i think its when I set the progress `progressView.progress = setProg` . Error will be gone if i comment this line..

Comment: Comment that line out and try printing out `setProg` inside the `setProgress` function, and if it does decrement the problem isn't with the method nor selector.

Comment: yes it does decrement.. `0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.4
0.3
0.2`

Comment: The `progressView.progress = setProg` seems the error, when i try setting it in viewDidLoad , it creates the same error..

Answer (score -1):

I think the error was fix when I delete and recreate the progressbar.. it may have been as MikeG suggested about incorrect connection on the outlet. Anyways thanks all for your help..