# Swift: Edit Mode, link editButtonItem() to IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I understand how to set my `UITableView` into edit mode, and how to dynamically create an edit button:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
}
```

But when I tap the edit button, I would like a new button to appear on the navigation bar (i.e. a 'plus'/'add' button). To do this I think I need to create an `IBAction`, but I don't know how to link the `editButtonItem()` to an action. Any ideas?

Comment: Just overwrite `setEditing:animated:` and add / remove the button respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, big thanks to Ahmed and vadian for their comments, but what I got working was this:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Toggles the edit button state
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    // Toggles the actual editing actions appearing on a table view
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)

    if (self.editing) {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self,
                            action: #selector(clickMe))

    } else {
        // we're not in edit mode 
        let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton
    }

}


func clickMe()
{
    print("Button Clicked")
}
```

As the edit button is pressed (and flips from Edit -> Done and back again) the code in the IF/ELSE statements will execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the default action of editButtonItem() by assigning a new function defined in your view controller to its action property.

```
editButtonItem().action = #selector(yourCustomAction(_:))

func yourCustomAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ahmed, apologises, but what do you mean by '#selector'?

Comment: refer to this answer to better understand swift selector: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift) and [https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-selector-syntax-sugar-81c8a8b10df3#.q25ftjr60](https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-selector-syntax-sugar-81c8a8b10df3#.q25ftjr60)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. This kills all of the built in functionality of the editButtonItem & it won't switch from "edit" to "done" on its own. Definitely override the setEditing method like @alias235 did