# Swift #selector issue

Tags: swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter

I'm new in Swift, i am using video lessons. But in current lesson i have an issue, and i can't solve it by myself.

The issue is with new #selector syntax in NSNotificationCenter, i used the old syntax and it didn't work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onPostsLoaded:", name: "postsLoaded", object: nil)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func onPostsLoaded(notif:AnyObject) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Please check the Screenshot:[How should I rewrite the yellow code (with selector) to make it work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lzYt.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's also works well :   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onPostsLoaded(_:)), name: "postsLoaded", object: nil)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.onPostsLoaded(_:)), name: "postsLoaded", object: nil)
```

Don't forget to replace `YourViewController` by the name of your controller, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onPostsLoaded(_:)), name: "postsLoaded", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answers above are the best, but don't forget the "_" in the targetAction as well, since you use Swift 3.0, see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537901/3143890