# Swift - scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval - NSInvocation

Tags: swift, timer

I want to schedule a function call in the future. I'm using Swift.

I want to callback a method that is private and returns a Promise (from PromiseKit)

All the example I've seen use

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, target: AnyObject, selector: Selector, userInfo: AnyObject?, repeats: Bool)
```

Fine. I've tried

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "connect", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

That fails with `No method declared with Objective-C selector 'connect'`.

What is Objective-C doing here??

Anyway it's suggested that I add `@objc` in front of my method `connect`. Fine. Well I can't because apparently `Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

If I wanted to use objective-C I'd not be writing Swift...

There's another `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` that is

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ti: NSTimeInterval, invocation: NSInvocation, repeats: Bool)
```

But from what I've read `NSInvocation` is not a Swift thing...

So I ended up creating a wrapper that does nothing other than calling `connect` and returning `Void` that Objective C can understand. It works but it feels very stupid. Is there a better Swift way?

Bonus: why can javascript do that as simply as `setTimeout(this.connect, 1)` and Swift has no built in way I can find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning with iOS 10 and Swift 3, it is possible to use (NS)Timer with a block closure and thus avoid Objective-C selector invocation when the timer fires:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false, block: { (Timer) in
            self.connect() // per the OP's example
        })
    }
```

In addition to avoiding the `@objc` decorator, using this technique allows you to invoke methods that include non-Objective-C-compatible parameter types such as enums and optionals.

Re: `setTimeout(this.connect, 1)` from the Javascript, if you don't need to cancel it, a more direct analogy in Swift 3 might be:

```
DispatchQueue.Main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute { self.connect() })
```

Which is pretty darn close given that you actually have a choice of which thread to run on ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> What is Objective-C doing here??

The reason for the need of Objective-C is that it dynamically binds the "call" (it is no call in Objective-C) at runtime, while Swift cannot do this. Swift is not able to have code in the timer class that "calls" a "function" not known at the compile time of `NSTimer`.

BTW: `NSTimer` uses `NSInvocation` (or something similar unswifty technology) to do the the "call". Therefore the usage of `NSTimer` is not more swifty, but the need for late binding is more obfuscated to make Swift developers feel better.

> If I wanted to use objective-C I'd not be writing Swift...

Even your code is completely written in Swift, it takes masses of benefits from Objective-C's late binding. Many of the core techniques of Cocoa are impossible to write in Swift, including responder chain, undo manager, Core Data, animations … (On the other hand you are able to define a  operator, what is a big progress in software engineering and describes the whole story.)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind Swift 2.2 / Xcode 7.3 has a new way to use selector: `Selector("funcName")` was changed to `#selector(ClassName.funcName)`

You should use `#selector`:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(YourClass.connect), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

OR `Selector("connect")`, however keep in mind that you'll receive a warning:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("connect"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift/24007769#24007769) in order to know how to use `Selector()`.

More info *Referencing the Objective-C selector* of a method
 [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md).

Comment: Yes both need the selector to be understandable by Objective-C, which was not my case since it was returning a Promise (from PromiseKit)

Comment: :) Sure. I mentioned it above though: "Well I can't because apparently `Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C`" but I agree code is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can invoke a timer:

```
// Specify the selector name as String
// Swift will give you a warning but this is handy if you have the function's name stored
// as a variable or need some dynamism
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerFired"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

// The recommended way since Swift 2.2 / 2.3 (can't remeber exactly)
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

And both assumes you have a function like this:

```
func timerFired() {
    print("Hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback for NSTimer needs to be accessible to Objective-C, even if you're using swift. In my case it meant two things:

- decorate the private method with `@objc` since by default private methods are not accessible to Objective-C from Swift classes.
- wrap my method in a method that calls it and returns nothing, so that the callback returns void. This was necessary since Objective-C didn't know how to handle the `Promise` type.

So at the end it looked like:

```
import PromiseKit

class bla : NSObject {
  private func myCallback() -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { fullfill, reject in
      // ...
    }
  }

  @objc private func myCallbackWrap -> Void {
    myCallback()
  }

  func startTimeout() -> Void {
      NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(myCallbackWrap), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }
}
```