# Quick q regarding Selectors in XCode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Basically, I have been using Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) by Apple for learning and I have come across some code that simply does not work - the Apple version as well.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), 
forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

And the errors are:

1. Expected ',' separator (between "action:" and "#selector" TWICE)
2. Expected expression in lists of expressions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: @gotnull - changed #selector -> @selector() yet still gives me error #2

Comment: What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Do you have a parameter of this action?

Comment: @dan - Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: It's too old version of Xcode.

Comment: The selector syntax that the sample code uses was added in Xcode 7.3

Comment: You can use without `#selector()`

Comment: Just say `button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", 
forControlEvents: .TouchDown)` instead

Comment: @AmateurUser - THANK YOU

Comment: @dan - can i update xcode without losing any previous work

Comment: Yes! Of course. No problem

Answer (score 0):

You must define funcion ratingButtonTapped() in your code.

Comment: and if you don't use xcode version 7.3 or later, you can try define selector like this:   
action : Selector("funcName")