# Selector in swift with two parameters not firing

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to use selector with two params

i Used this code for this

```
func yourButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject, rcd :  NSManagedObject)
{ }
```

i have to pass param record1

```
cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourButtonClicked(_:record1)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

it shows error missing arg rcd in call

can anyone correct me ?

Comment: should check this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting selector in `addTarget` method you are just saying to your object that it should search "action" method with given parameter names signature in  "target" object and invoke it when event happends. You are not able to provide properties or variables that should be used as parameters in call. If you will read [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW21) for `UIControl` for example, you will find that `addTarget` method allows only three signature of your action.

To solve your problem, you may declare property and use it in your action:

```
var rcd: NSManagedObject!
func yourButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
    //use rcd property, keeping it in actual state
}

func someMethod() {
    rcd = record1
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}
```