# ios Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'String' swift 3

Tags: ios, selector, swift3

[image]

I have updated my code to Swift 3 and now getting the error above. I think there is something wrong with the way `selector` is called. Anyone please help me, What is wrong.

Comment: Found that link where it is all explained.
[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Answer (score 13):

Just change your selector syntax with swift 3 selector syntax like this.

```
 #selector(self.hideKeyboard)
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for Selector has been changed in Swift 3. You don't need to add round brackets after selector name if there is no parameter in the selector.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution can try this.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

// function which is triggered when handleTap is called
 func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     print("Hello World")
  }
```

I know it's loo late to answer, but it can help others.