# Action on a UIButton doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to understand the MVVM pattern by learning from a tutorial ([link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.3p1kc2gov)) and **I can't get an action I've added to a UIButton to work** (I'm using Swift 3.0). I've tried debugging for hours, studied this thread ([@selector in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)) and others, and I'm still stuck. When I click the button, nothing happens at all. I tried various syntax options with the selector and I think what you see below is correct. I think the protocol I'm using might be contributing to the problem but, given my limited experience with protocols, I could be completely wrong about that.

I'll put all the code here in case anybody wants to drop it into Xcode. The action in question here is in my `UIViewController` that I add to `showGreetingButton`:

```
class GreetingViewController : UIViewController {
  let showGreetingButton = UIButton()
  @IBOutlet weak var greetingLabel: UILabel!

  var viewModel: GreetingViewModelProtocol! {
    didSet {
      self.viewModel.greetingDidChange = { [unowned self] viewModel in
        self.greetingLabel.text = viewModel.greeting
      }
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showGreetingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    showGreetingButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
    showGreetingButton.setTitle("Show Greeting", for: .normal)

    // I add the action here:
    showGreetingButton.addTarget(self.viewModel, action: #selector(GreetingViewModel.showGreeting), for: .touchUpInside)

    showGreetingButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false    
    view.addSubview(showGreetingButton)
    let buttonTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showGreetingButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
    let buttonLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: showGreetingButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    showGreetingButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([buttonTop, buttonLeading])

    let model = Person(firstName: "David", lastName: "Blaine")

    let viewModel = GreetingViewModel(person: model)

    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
}
```

My view model is called GreetingViewModel which adopts a protocol:

```
protocol GreetingViewModelProtocol: class {      
  var greeting: String? { get }
  var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())? { get set }
  init(person: Person)
  func showGreeting()
}

class GreetingViewModel : GreetingViewModelProtocol {
  let person: Person
  var greeting: String? {
    didSet {
      self.greetingDidChange?(self)
    }
  }

  var greetingDidChange: ((GreetingViewModelProtocol) -> ())?

  required init(person: Person) {
    self.person = person
  }

  @objc func showGreeting() {
    self.greeting = "Hello" + " " + self.person.firstName + " " + self.person.lastName
  }
}
```

And my simple model is:

```
struct Person {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
}
```

Any help would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these lines to before you set your button's target:

```
let viewModel = GreetingViewModel(person: model)
self.viewModel = viewModel
```

Right now you are adding `self.viewModel` as the target, but `self.viewModel` is `nil`

Comment: I also had to move `let model = Person(firstName: "David", lastName: "Blaine") ` with those two lines but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Vinodh, @beyoulf's answer was better before you edited it because it made it clear that the important thing was for those lines to be before `showGreetingButton.addTarget(self.viewModel, action: #selector(GreetingViewModel.showGreeting), for: .touchUpInside)`. Your edit makes it less clear.

Comment: Will replace the old one

Comment: Thank you, @Vinodh.