# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, selector

I have a method called `selectionDidFinish(controller:)` in a delegate to dismiss the viewController the delegate presented. The presented controller, which adopts my `Dismissable` protocol, has a `UIBarButtonItem` with an action attached to it that should call the `selectionDidFinish(controller:)` method but it's giving me the "Argument of '#selector' does not 'refer' to an initializer or method" error.

The error is in this presented `UIViewController`:

```
class FormulaInfoViewController: UIViewController, Dismissable {

    weak var dismissalDelegate: DismissalDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Xcode doesn't like this selector
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissalDelegate?.selectionDidFinish(self)))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that the `dismissalDelegate` is getting set properly to `FormulasTableViewController` so I can't understand why it can't see `dismissalDelegate?.selectionDidFinish(self))`.

The relevant code of my presenting `UIViewController` is:

```
class FormulasTableViewController: UITableViewController, DismissalDelegate {

  let formulas: [CalculationFormula] = [
    CalculationFormula.epley,
    CalculationFormula.baechle,
    CalculationFormula.brzychi,
    CalculationFormula.lander,
    CalculationFormula.lombardi,
    CalculationFormula.mayhewEtAl,
    CalculationFormula.oConnerEtAl]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let liftInfoImage = UIImage(named: "info_icon")
    let liftInfoButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: liftInfoImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.segueToFormulaInfo(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = liftInfoButton 
  }

  func selectionDidFinish(controller: UIViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
    let vc = nav.topViewController as! Dismissable
    vc.dismissalDelegate = self
    }

  func segueToFormulaInfo(sender: UIButton) {
      performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToFormulaInfo", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I've done all kinds of research on how to use `#selector` and I thought [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift?rq=1) had all the answers, but it doesn't.

I've tried this Dismissable protocol with and without exposing it to `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol Dismissable: class {
    weak var dismissalDelegate: DismissalDelegate? {
        get set }
    }
```

And I've also tried it with my DismissalDelegate protocol:

```
@objc protocol DismissalDelegate : class {
    func selectionDidFinish(controller: UIViewController)
}

extension DismissalDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func selectionDidFinish(viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I can't expose my protocol extension to `@objc` - is that why this doesn't work? Is my `#selector` really the problem here? Does it have something to do with my protocols?

**EDIT: Final fix**

Based on the accepted answer, I added a function to do the dismissal:

```
func dismiss() {
    dismissalDelegate?.selectionDidFinish(self)
}
```

and then called the selector like this:

```
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismiss))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the `action` parameter specify an arbitrary expression.  It needs to invoke a specific selector - a class and function in that class.

You will need to create a function in your class that invokes the delegate method:

```
class FormulaInfoViewController: UIViewController, Dismissable {

    weak var dismissalDelegate: DismissalDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(FormulaInfoViewController.selectionDidFinish)
    }  

    @objc func selectionDidFinish() {
        self.dismissalDelegate?.selectionDidFinish(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: ...to the extent that Xcode will even autocomplete with any know method of the class whose name you typed before the ".". It's not like Objective-C (or Swift 2.2) anymore, where you could just pass any string whatsoever and have it crash at runtime! :-)