# Timer only executing function once

Tags: swift, function, timer

So the timer works once but after the first time it doesnt work anymore... What's the problem and how can it be fixed? Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 let myTimer : Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 7, target: self, selector: (selector: "functionOne"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
    func functionOne()
    {
       print("hello")

    }
```

Comment: FYI - your Swift 3 selector syntax is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 7.0, target: self, selector: #selector(functionOne), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func functionOne () { 
   print("hello") 
}
```

Output:

[image]