# Unrecognized selector error in my code?

Tags: swift

I have the following method that would call the "updateMapView(sender:UIButton)" method but I get the unrecognized selector error. I have set the action: attribute with other variations such as updateMapView:sender and stuff so it's not a problem there. What might be it though?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MapsTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MapsTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
    }

    let map = fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity.object(at: indexPath)
    // Configure Cell
    cell.mapNameLabel.text = map.name
    cell.button.accessibilityHint = map.name
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "updateMapView:", for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Rename the method to `func updateMapView(_ sender: UIButton)`

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method so it looks like `func updateMapView(_ sender: UIButton)` and use `#selector(updateMapView)` as your action.