# UIButton unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am using a custom cell with UICollectionView, I need to define UIButton programmatically per cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ClinicListCell
    cell.title.text = clinicNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.subTitle.text = clinicSubs[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: clinicImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.profileBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.profileBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("profileBtnClicked:")), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

And I have defined the following selector method in the same class.

```
class func profileBtnClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    print("Selected")
}
```

I've tried by removing class/static from the selector method, but it always give me `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error, where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the full/complete error message (including the info *which* selector is unrecognized)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this 
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ClinicListCell
    cell.title.text = clinicNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.subTitle.text = clinicSubs[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: clinicImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.profileBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.profileBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.profileBtnClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    return cell
}


class func profileBtnClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    print("Selected")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Comment: Sorry, but the `class func` qualifier is wrong. You need an *instance* method or else you won't be able to access your view controller properties and methods.

Comment: An answer is more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if you *explain* the problem, instead of posting code only. What is wrong in OP's code and how is it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `@objc` to your method, not strictly required in this case, and remove the `class` or `static` qualifier.

By the way, since Swift 2.2, you can create a `Selector` from a Swift function using the `#selector` operator. For instance:

```
let clicked = #selector(self.profileBtnClicked(sender:))
```

for:

```
@objc func profileBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    ...
}
```

Technically, for `NSObject` based classes, the `@obj` qualifier should only be required for `private` methods.

Comment: Tried both, does not work.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Have you tried the `@objc` and `#selector` combination? I updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Is the profileBtn linked up probably? This error may happens when the name has changed or the link between the button in interface builder and the variable is removed.

Or you can try with the syntax

```
cell.profileBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector("profileBtnClicked:"), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: If it was not linked up, it shouldn't throw me unrecognized selector error right? from the error what I understand is, it cannot find the selector method.