# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method (swift 3)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, selector

I am setting up swipe recognition in my SKScene, and I found that hard coding all the recognizers takes time and isn't really neat, so I decided to use a for-loop, and a dictionary that contains `UISwipeRecognizer`s as keys, and `()` functions as values. The problem is that it gives me the error in the title while trying to add the target using `recognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionForRecognizer[recognizer]!))`

Here is the code:

```
class xxxxx: SKScene {

let rightSwipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let leftSwipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let upSwipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let downSwipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

var swipeRecognizers: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer] {
    return [rightSwipeRecognizer, leftSwipeRecognizer, upSwipeRecognizer, downSwipeRecognizer]
}

var directionForRecognizer: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] {
    return [
        rightSwipeRecognizer : .right,
        leftSwipeRecognizer : .left,
        upSwipeRecognizer : .up,
        downSwipeRecognizer : .down
    ]
}

func didSwipeRight() {}
func didSwipeLeft() {}
func didSwipeUp() {}
func didSwipeDown() {}

var functionForRecognizer: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer : ()] {
    return [
        rightSwipeRecognizer : didSwipeRight(),
        leftSwipeRecognizer : didSwipeLeft(),
        upSwipeRecognizer : didSwipeUp(),
        downSwipeRecognizer : didSwipeDown()
    ]
}

func setupSwipeRecognizers() {
    for recognizer in swipeRecognizers {
        recognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionForRecognizer[recognizer]!))
        recognizer.direction = directionForRecognizer[recognizer]!
        self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)
    setupSwipeRecognizers()
}
```

}

Btw, i tried putting `@objc` while declaring the functions, but it didn't work. Also, I tried exposing the class to NSObject, by removing inheritance from SKScene and conforming to NSObject, and still, it didn't work. Moreover, i cannot conform the class to a UIKit class, cz i need it as a SKScene, and even, i tried conforming it to a UIViewController (without SKScene, of course), but still didn't work,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't possible with Swift's `#selector`. Instead, insert instances of the `Selector` class directly into the dictionary.

You'll also need to annotate with @objc

```
@objc // This annotation isn't required in Swift 3, but will be in Swift 4
func didSwipeRight() {}

var functionForRecognizer: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer : Selector] {
    return [
        rightSwipeRecognizer : #selector(didSwipeRight)
    ]
}

recognizer.addTarget(self, action: functionForRecognizer[recognizer]))
```

For a detailed explanation of `#selector` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/5099014). Summary, `#selector` is a compiler construct for Swift that ensures the exact selector/method exists, including the class it should exist on. It looks at the actual contents within its parentheses to see if it is a known method, and `functionForRecognizer[recognizer]` is not a method name, it is a variable + subscript method call.