# Trigger textFieldShouldReturn from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to add a `UIBarButtonItem` that triggers my `textFieldShouldReturn`, but I get this error:

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

**UIBarButtonItem**

```
func addToolBar(textField: UITextField) {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Done",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(textFieldShouldReturn(textField))) //** ERROR **
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

**textFieldShouldReturn:**

```
@objc func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) {
  print("hi there!")
}
```

The error suggests that I should need to add `objc` to my `textFieldShouldReturn`, but I already have that.  I also already tried the following:

- [Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511973/argument-of-selector-does-not-refer-to-an-objc-method-property-or-initia/41512253)
- [Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090845/argument-of-selector-does-not-refer-to-an-objc-method)
- [Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334786/argument-of-selector-does-not-refer-to-an-initializer-or-method)
- [How to set the action for a UIBarButtonItem in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641350/how-to-set-the-action-for-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift)

**Does anyone understand how I can set up my `UIBarButtonItem` to trigger my `textFieldShouldReturn`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here.

1. The `textFieldShouldReturn` method is a delegate method of `UITextFieldDelegate`. It should only be called by a `UITextField`. It has one parameter - the text field.
2. The `UIBarButtonItem` target/selector needs to be a method specific to handling the button being pressed. The selector needs to have one of two possible signatures. That can be a method with no parameter or a method with one parameter that will be the `UIBarButtonItem` that triggered the event.
3. You are trying to call a mismatched `UITextFieldDelegate` method as the selector to your `UIBarButtonItem`. That simply won't work.

If you want both the text field delegate and the button selector to perform the same action, then have each of the two corresponding methods call a 3rd, common method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) {
    processReturn()
}

@objc func barButtonAction(_ button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    processReturn()
}

func processReturn() {
    // Do whatever is needed
}
```

And setup the bar button item with:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "Done",
        style: .done,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(barButtonAction)
```

If your `processReturn` method needs a reference to the text field then add that parameter. The trick will be obtaining a reference to the text field from the `barButtonAction` method. It can't be passed as a parameter to that method so you will need to have a property that references the text field.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy! This worked for me and I was able to get the reference to the textField as well too.

Answer (score 0):

Here using this you can call textFieldSholdReturn method from a button Action :

```
var textField : UITextField!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Fixed space
        let fixed = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        fixed.width = 10

        //Text
        let text = UIBarButtonItem(title: "My Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
        text.setTitleTextAttributes([
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.normal)

        //TextField
        textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.textColor = UIColor.blue
        let border = CALayer()
        let width : CGFloat = 2.0
        border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height-width, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let textFieldButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: textField)

        //Search Button
        let search = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.search, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.callExplictly(sender:)))

        //Flexible Space
        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

        //Toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20 , width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
        toolbar.isTranslucent = false
        toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        toolbar.items = [fixed, text, fixed, textFieldButton, flexible, search]
        view.addSubview(toolbar)
    }
```

You need to use a method as selector Not just directly calling Delgate method of textfield

-- Adding Selector to a UIBarButton :

```
 //Search Button
 let search = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.search, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.callExplictly(sender:)))
```

Here required Method to call the delegate Method

```
@objc func callExplictly(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("its called")
        if let textField = textField, let textFieldDelegate = textField.delegate {
            if textFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldReturn!(textField) {
                textField.endEditing(true)
            }
        }
 //here let textField --- Here I am just using. reference to TextField used  = textField --- this is textField declared and being used in Bar 
 //I am calling textField.endEditing(true) to dismiss opened Keyboard as Done button refer that My action required on TF is completed now I can Dismiss keyboard too.
 // As here textFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldReturn!  -- (!) this symbolises as textFieldShouldReturn is a delegate method of TextField and I am accessing that using a reference which is not of textField Type So I am using ! as optional so, it dont jump over the function and call it

    }

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        //Hide the keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Here is Delegate method which is called

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        print("Called")

        //Hide the keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Also check my code file for your reference :

```
Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8kF1Gedr7fcTdEX29WX1JvYlU
```

Comment: 1. Where does `textField` come from inside the `callExplicitly` method? 2. Why is there a `!` when calling `textFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldReturn!(textField)`? 3. Why are you calling `endEditing`? You will have already resigned the first responder.

Comment: Did you checked my Code File I shared here ? if let textField // I am creating a reference = textField // this TF is used in Bar

Comment: Please check my updated Answer here I Posted some more comments there

Comment: @iOSGeek This didn't work for me, but as always, thanks for a response. As a side note, it seems as though linking to a personal google drive file would be bad practice as it easily could lead SO users to a potentially malicious file.. just food for thought