# How to add an action to a UITextField using selector

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, selector

After viewing different options on the Internet, I never found a working implementation option how to do it. I just want to add listener to UITextField. Have some code

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate

  @IBOutlet weak var textRegion: UITextField!

textRegion.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("myTargetFunction:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
    func myTargetFunction() {
        print("It works!")
    }
```

but it does not work, have `THREAD 1 : SIGNAL SIGABRT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for your `selector`. Use this one instead `#selector(myTargetFunction)`.

The entire code:

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
textRegion.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
```

And then declare the function:

```
func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) {
    print("touchDown for \(textField.tag)")
}
```

Comment: Error 
Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'myTargetFunction(textField:)'

Comment: `func myTargetFunction(textField: UITextField) { ... }` need to be outside of `viewDidLoad`, it is right?