# Pull to refresh on WKWebview

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to make a pull to refresh on WKWebView. When I try to pull and refresh, I get this error:`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GoldenVillage.AvailabilityViewController mymethodforref:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111d18e50'`

How to fix it?

My code in viewDidAppear :

```
self.availabilityWebview = WKWebView(
     frame: self.containerView.bounds,
     configuration: config
)
self.view = self.availabilityWebview!
refController.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 50, refController.bounds.size.width, refController.bounds.size.height) 
refController.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("mymethodforref:")), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
refController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
availabilityWebview?.scrollView.addSubview(refController)

self.noNetwork.text! = ""
if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewID = crew["crew_id"] as? String {

let url = URL(string: "http://ec2-52-221-231-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/gv/available-schedule_3.php?id=\(crewID)")
self.availabilityWebview!.load(URLRequest(url:url!))


func mymethodforref(refresh:UIRefreshControl){
    availabilityWebview?.reload()
    refController.endRefreshing()
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}
```

Comment: instead of `Selector(("mymethodforref:")` try `#selector(mymethodforref(refresh:))`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 It worked! Can I ask another question? How to change the position of the refresh controller? I added the position code on answer but I get error. how to convert CGReactMake to CGReact?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: 1) Post another question if you're stuck somewhere else. 2) it's `CGRect`

Comment: I agree with @LinusGeffarth ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: you can use `CGRect(x: , y: , width: , height:)`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 ok thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
Selector(("mymethodforref:")
```

try

```
#selector(mymethodforref(refresh:))
```