# How to use #selector correctly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding a reload button for iOS in-app web browser using `WKWebView.reload`
I tried two options, and the two options works for me the same but I want to know what is the technical correct option to use with #selector. Is it `#selector(class.method)` or `#selector (object.method)`  ?

Here is the first:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
view = webView
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(WKWebView.reload))
```

and here the second one:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
view = webView
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(webView))
```

Here is the full code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: webView, action: #selector(WKWebView.reload))
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, my recommendation is using `#selector(target.method)`.

When you pass `self` as `target` then, `#selector(self.method)`, passing `webView` to `target`, then `#selector(webView.method)`.

`#selector` is just an encoded ObjC method name (which does not include class name), so both `#selector(ClassName.method)` and `#selector(object.method)` should work. But you can expect a better compile-time diagnostic with `#selector(target.method)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `let webView = WKWebView()` is creating a new instance of yours.. it won't work independently of your `#selector`

try it out:

```
func reloadWebView() {
    webView.reload()
}
```

your call:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.reloadWebView))
```

Comment: No it works, you can try the full code I added to my question, but first don't forget to embed your view controller in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

The function `reload` is not declared as **@objc**, therefore, it won't work as selector in swift. You may want to create a function in your ViewController and call the reload function from there.

```
@objc func reloadWebView() {
    webView.reload()
}
```

and your selector will look like this
`#selector(reloadWebView)`

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414969-reload

Comment: No it works, you can try the full code I added to my question, but first don't forget to embed your view controller in a navigation controller.