# Understanding Tapgesture syntax - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitapgesturerecognizer

Suppose I have the following function:

```
 @objc func action(_ gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer){}
```

Now to call the function, we usually use a syntax like so:

```
let mygesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(action(_:)))
```

What does the syntax `action(_:)` actually mean? How are we passing the value of the input parameter `gesture` required by the function? Doesn't it has to be something like `action(_: somevalue)`

From my guess, we are only providing the access to the function by writing `action(_:)`. And the function is actually called by passing the `mygesture` variable itself when the tap gesture is triggered. Is that correct?

Comment: This is part of the "Target-Action" mechanism. You can read [more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html) (last paragraph for UIKit).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007718/1630618

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. You're passing the pointer of the function to the gesture recognizer.