# Adding an action to back swipes swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back

I have changed the back button in my navigation bar in one of my view controllers to a custom button and gave that button an action to do when pressed by:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backArrow"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.back))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

This worked perfectly and I was able to keep the back swipe to pop the view controller by using:

```
self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

in my navigation controller file. Unfortunately, when I back swipe, I can not (or I haven't figured out) call on the `back()` function in my view controller that changes the back button. How and where can I detect that I am swiping to go back so I can call on the back function in that specific view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this answer you can just subscribe to the gesture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893464/1484378

```
// In UINavigationController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.handlePopGesture))
}

@objc func handlePopGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        back()
    }
}
```

You will probably have to add some custom logic to access your view controller's back method like: `if let vc = visibleViewController as? MyViewController { vc.back() }`

Comment: The pleasure is mine.

Comment: I don't want to kill the joy but this does not guarantee that the user navigates back. It only tells you that he has started the gesture. Even the .end state does not ensure that the user leaves the current screen. You can hold on to the swipe gesture and if you don't let it go immediately it will not transition to the previous ViewController unless the gesture translation has passed 50% percent of the screen.
However, I could not find a way to ensure that the user visits the previous screen and does not cancel or stop the swipe back gesture. But be aware that this ca cause some unexpected be