# Adding action to a back swipe Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back

In my app I have a UINavigationController that puts a navigation bar on all of my ViewControllers and in every ViewController I have a custom back button. In one specific ViewController I need to send some data when going back to the previous ViewController. I was able to do this when the user presses the back button with a custom function, but this function is ignored when user swipes to go back.

I tried using this answer: [Adding an action to back swipes swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082589/adding-an-action-to-back-swipes-swift-4) but calling `visibleViewController` or `topViewController` in the navigation controller only gets the view controller that we're going to (the previous ViewController, not the current one). I need the function inside the ViewController we're in before the user swipes back.

How can I call on the `back` function I made inside my current ViewController to send the data from that ViewController to the ViewController we'll pop to.

Comment: Have you checked `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods? I am not sure if it has something for this.

Comment: Why not use `viewDidDisappear` in the view controller class?

Comment: Maybe create a **weak** var **optional** in your second view controller that store a reference to the previous viewcontroller, then override `viewWillDisappear(_:)` method in the second view controller and in that func pass the data.

Comment: Or just use your back function inside `viewWillDisappear(_:)` method.

Comment: Wow the `viewWillDisappear(_:)` worked! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to use `viewWillDisappear(_:)` and just put the function you made here.